# Не запускается приложение. Точка входа не найдена

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

Имеется статическая библиотека и консольное приложение, которое использует эту библиотеку. В библиотеке используются только средства STL. Сборка и компиляция проходит без ошибок и предупреждений. Среда разработки - Clion, использую MinGw, версия GCC 4.9.3. Внутри среды приложение работает как положено, но при запуске собранной релизной версии через исполняемый exe файл появляется ошибка:
[image: error]

Собирал на Linux, GCC 4.8.4 - ничего подобного нет, все работает нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Это означает, что в той DLL, где находится функция __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length эта функция не вписана в таблицу экспорта функций. Прежде всего следует проверить саму функцию в ее ДЛЛ, правильно ли она объявлена и экспортирована. Далее, могу предложить по-играть с форматом, в который компилируется ДЛЛ. Возможно компилятор неправильно собирает ДЛЛ в том формате, который вы задали (или который задан по-умолчанию).

Если проблема не пропадет - скачайте любой експорт вивер, например [этот](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html), и проверьте, объявлена там эта функция на самом деле в таблице экспорта, или нет. Если объявлена - надо копать основное приложение, разбираться почему оно не видит функцию. Возможно в основном приложении таблице импорта неправильно указана DLL-источник функции или еще что...